# I am unable to run any tests without Rails throwing an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, activerecord

So I'm currently studying tests and I was trying to do a simple asset_not test and noticed when I ran `$ rails test test/models/tweet_test.rb`

I get :

```
Error:
TweetTest#test_should_not_create_tweet_without_user:
ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation: RuntimeError: NOT NULL constraint failed: comments.tweet_id
```

tweet_test.rb

```
require "test_helper"

class TweetTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test "should not create tweet without user" do
    tweet = Tweet.new
    assert_not tweet.save, "Tweet is able to save without user association"
  end
end
```

tweet.rb

```
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :tweet, optional: true
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :likes, as: :likeable

  validates :body, length: { maximum: 240 }, allow_blank: false, unless: :tweet_id
```

comment.rb

```
belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :tweet
  has_many :likes, as: :likeable
  validates :body, length: { maximum: 240 }, allow_blank: false
```

schema

```
 ActiveRecord::Schema[7.0].define(version: 2023_01_07_162453) do
  create_table "comments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "tweet_id", null: false
    t.bigint "user_id", null: false
    t.text "body", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["tweet_id"], name: "index_comments_on_tweet_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_comments_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "likes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "user_id", null: false
    t.integer "likeable_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "likeable_type"
    t.index ["likeable_id", "likeable_type"], name: "index_likes_on_likeable_id_and_likeable_type"
    t.index ["likeable_id"], name: "index_likes_on_likeable_id"
    t.index ["user_id", "likeable_id", "likeable_type"], name: "index_likes_on_user_id_and_likeable_id_and_likeable_type", unique: true
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_likes_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "tweets", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "user_id"
    t.text "body"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "tweet_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.boolean "admin", default: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.string "username"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

  add_foreign_key "comments", "tweets"
  add_foreign_key "comments", "users"
  add_foreign_key "likes", "users"
end
```

stack trace when I run rails

```
rails  test test/models/tweet_test.rb
D, [2023-01-06T22:08:48.613375 #7565] DEBUG -- :    (0.0ms)  PRAGMA foreign_keys
D, [2023-01-06T22:08:48.613423 #7565] DEBUG -- :    (0.0ms)  PRAGMA defer_foreign_keys
D, [2023-01-06T22:08:48.613457 #7565] DEBUG -- :    (0.0ms)  PRAGMA defer_foreign_keys = ON
D, [2023-01-06T22:08:48.613481 #7565] DEBUG -- :    (0.0ms)  PRAGMA foreign_keys = OFF
D, [2023-01-06T22:08:48.613554 #7565] DEBUG -- :   TRANSACTION (0.0ms)  begin transaction
D, [2023-01-06T22:08:48.613984 #7565] DEBUG -- :   Fixtures Load (0.4ms)  DELETE FROM "comments";
DELETE FROM "tweets";
DELETE FROM "users";
INSERT INTO "comments" ("id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (980190962, '2023-01-07 03:08:48.611501', '2023-01-07 03:08:48.611501');
INSERT INTO "comments" ("id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (298486374, '2023-01-07 03:08:48.611501', '2023-01-07 03:08:48.611501');
INSERT INTO "tweets" ("id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (980190962, '2023-01-07 03:08:48.612217', '2023-01-07 03:08:48.612217');
INSERT INTO "tweets" ("id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (298486374, '2023-01-07 03:08:48.612217', '2023-01-07 03:08:48.612217');
INSERT INTO "users" ("id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (980190962, '2023-01-07 03:08:48.612632', '2023-01-07 03:08:48.612632');
INSERT INTO "users" ("id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (298486374, '2023-01-07 03:08:48.612632', '2023-01-07 03:08:48.612632')
D, [2023-01-06T22:08:48.614166 #7565] DEBUG -- :   TRANSACTION (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
D, [2023-01-06T22:08:48.614213 #7565] DEBUG -- :    (0.0ms)  PRAGMA defer_foreign_keys = 0
D, [2023-01-06T22:08:48.614237 #7565] DEBUG -- :    (0.0ms)  PRAGMA foreign_keys = 1
```

test/application_system_test_case.rb

```
require "test_helper"

class ApplicationSystemTestCase < ActionDispatch::SystemTestCase
  driven_by :selenium, using: :chrome, screen_size: [1400, 1400]
end
```

/test/fixtures/comment.yml

```
comment: 
 id: 1
 tweet_id: 1
 user_id: 1
 body: "test comment"
```

/test/fixtures/tweet.yml

```
tweet: 
 body: "test tweet"
 user_id: 1
 id: 1
```

test/fixtures/user.yml

```
user: 
 id: 1
 name: "tester"
 email: "email@test.com"
 username: "testingman"
 encrypted_password: 123456
```

comments migration file

```
class CreateComments < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    create_table :comments do |t|
      t.references :tweet, null: false, foreign_key: true
      t.references :user, null: false, foreign_key: true
      t.text :body, null: false
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I've used integration tests a little on my first project and I'm now trying to become familiar with all tests and this is really confusing me.

thanks,

Comment: Your test tries to save a `Tweet` but the error is regarding a comment so what you have posted is not the entire context of the issue. Additionally posting screenshots is frowned upon instead copy the full stack trace and post it in a code block.

Comment: I removed the screenshot and included only the first few lines of the error instead. Went looking online to find how to log a stack trace so let me know if I what I just posted is what you were referring to.

Comment: also all code in all other tests are commented out and are not running. all other tests were either generated by devise or rails

Comment: I'm pretty sure the error is caused by your fixtures. `fixtures :all` is  loading `/test/fixtures/comment.yml` which doesn't have a tweet attached to it.

Comment: You also have an issue in that all your foreign key columns are very likely the wrong type. You have defined them as int while Rails uses bigint for primary keys. Some DB's are sloppy enough to allow it but for example Postgres will not. Use the `references` macro instead for setting up foreign key columns.

Comment: to be clear, are you saying I should change the data type for every obj_id to t.bigint?

Comment: also the '/test/fixtures/comment.yml'  file is indeed empty. could you give some advice on how to properly attach tweets to comments and so on? I will attach the 'comment.yml' file to the post now

Comment: updated schema as per advice

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my problem was relatively simple. I removed the default code in the `text/fixtures/comment.yml` , `text/fixtures/tweet.yml`, and the `text/fixtures/user.yml` files.

in all three files the default code is

```
one: {}
# column: value
#
two: {}
# column: value
```

I removed all of that. my code worked immediately. I have no clue why that is but it works. I believe may be the empty hash exactly that's the root cause but it's beyond me.